# How to enable syntax highlighting for CUDA .cu and .cuh files in Vim?

Tags: vim, cuda, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I found that my `~/.vimrc` file has `syntax on` but it didn't work for any CUDA file (`.cu`).

Not sure to how to do it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add these two lines to ~/.vimrc:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cu set ft=cuda
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cuh set ft=cuda
```

And put [cuda.vim](http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/syntax/cuda.vim) in ~/.vim/syntax/

Have fun!

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you might be missing the syntax highlighting file for vim.  You should check your `/usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax` directory for `cuda.vim`.  That directory will vary depending on your system and version of vim.

If your version of vim does not come with `cuda.vim`, you can download this [cuda.vim](http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/syntax/cuda.vim) file and place it in ~/.vim/syntax/.

**Update:** add the following lines in your `~/.vimrc` as @BenjiWiebe recommended:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cu set filetype=cuda
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cuh set filetype=cuda
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't sudo permission. Is there some workaround?

Comment: do what @BenjiWiebe recommended and create a directory named '.vim' in your home directory and drop the file there.  vim should search for it and use it.  His answer may be best overall.

Comment: Recent versions of vim indeed include this `cuda.vim` file. So no need to download it manually.

Comment: namespaces are missing from this.

Answer (score 3):

how about [that](http://lifeofaprogrammergeek.blogspot.fr/2008/07/using-vim-for-cuda.html), does this work ?

```
cd /usr/share/vim/vim*/syntax
sudo cp cpp.vim cu.vim
echo "au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cu set ft=cu" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: This should work, too, but it uses C++ highlighting (not "real" CUDA highlighting).

Answer (score 1):

It's been long since the question was originally asked, but I found myself having almost the same issue and not being able to solve it by following the previous answers.

In my case, vim would automatically highlight .cu files (I'm using vim 80, which already has cuda.vim in /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/), but ignore .cuh ones. To solve this, I edited /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim and added

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cuh         setf cuda
```

And that was it!