# vim - how to add doxygen highlighting to other filetypes, such as CUDA

Tags: vim, cuda, doxygen

I am programming in CUDA and whereas my C and C++ files automatically get doxygen highlighting by setting

```
let g:load_doxygen_syntax=1
```

in `~/.vimrc`, my cuda files (`.cu` and `.cuh`) do not. How can I add doxygen highlighting to them, on top of the already existing [CUDA highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128961/how-to-let-vi-highlight-syntax-for-cuda-script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
au Syntax cuda
        \ if (exists('b:load_doxygen_syntax') && b:load_doxygen_syntax)
        \       || (exists('g:load_doxygen_syntax') && g:load_doxygen_syntax)
        \   | runtime! syntax/doxygen.vim
        \ | endif
```

Add the filetypes you want `doxygen` highlighting for as a comma-separated list after `au Syntax`. This snippet (taken from `syntax/synload.vim`) respects the `load_doxygen_syntax` setting.